# Every step function is a linear combination of elementary step functions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

If $J$ is any subinterval of $[a, b]$ and if $\phi_J (x) := 1$ for $x \in J$ and  $\phi_J (x) := 0$  elsewhere on $[a, b]$, we say that $\phi_J$ is an elementary step function on $[a, b]$. Then to show that every step function is a linear
combination of elementary step functions.

I have shown that each elementary step function on $[a, b]$ is Riemann Integrable. But finding difficulty to show that every step function is a linear
combination of elementary step functions.

Comment: Look up the definition of a step function. It should follow rather directly from the definition.

Comment: Which definition of "step function" are you using? [Some definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) *define* it as a linear combination of "indicator functions of intervals," which you call "elementary step functions."

Comment: I second the commenters above: usually step functions are defined as linear combinations of elementary step functions, therefore there is nothing to prove.

Comment: I have got the problem from EX: 7.2.5 of Bartle Sherbert , Introduction to Real Analysis.

Comment: Instead of naming the book you should answer the question: What is the definition of "step function" here? Nobody can possibly answer the question without that information. (If you're not sure what the definition is you should note that _you_ cannot answer the question without knowing the definition - should have looked that up first!)

Answer (score 1):

Let the step function be $f(x)=F_k$ for $x\in J_k:=[x_k,x_{k+1}]$, where the $x_k$ are the jump locations.

Then $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nF_k\phi_{J_k}(x).$$

Indeed, for $x\in J_i$ (using Kronecker's delta),

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nF_k\delta_{ik}=F_j.$$